# use different variable name than "script.src"

Tags: javascript, variables, escaping, eval

The following code is used to dynamically execute an external javascript file:

```
var script = document.createElement("script"); script.src = "http://www.example.com/test.js"; document.body.appendChild(script);
```

I was wondering, can i replace script.src with another name, preferably without a dot? Or somehow use eval alongside with unescape to decode the dot from e.g %252E?. I know how to do it with strings, but with a variable name i'm not sure.

Comment: You want to replace `script.src` with a variable. Why? What's the actual problem you're dealing with? And why do you care if there's a dot?

Comment: @CrazyTrain You can read my last question, this has been solved. Thanks for ignorantly thumbing down my question. Have a nice day.

Comment: Why would I read your last question? You posted a question here. If  you can't figure out how to evaluate the property name from a variable, then believe me, you're not the one to be calling people ignorant. ...I am having very a nice day, thank you.

Comment: You need to understand how strings and expressions and statements work.

Comment: Could you add more details about what you're actually trying to accomplish with this (and your previous question)? It really feels like you are approaching the problem the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use indexer notation:

```
script['src'] = ...
```

Comment: Purely for future reference though, can you somehow use unescape and eval on a variable name?

Comment: but how would it be with a variable name? this doesn't work: `unescape(unescape(script%252Esrc))` = ....

Comment: @Tom: That's invalid syntax.  You need a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that `script.src` is a variable name is incorrect.

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
```

The above line creates a script tag and assigns it to a variable called `script`.

```
script.src = "http://www.example.com/test.js";
```

The above line sets the **src attribute** of the element you created and assigned to the variable `script`. This is equivalent to:

```
script.setAttribute("src","http://www.example.com/test.js");
```

Comment: You completely ignored my question.

Comment: I didn't, I just said it was irrelevant because based on an incorrect assumption. Your title says that script.src is a variable name, which is not true.